# What is this document marked "Palestine Bearer Bond"?

Tags: british-empire, palestine, identification

I found this paper from the 1950s
[image]

Answer (score 8):

A simple google search indicates that it is probably a [Government of Palestine War Loan Bearer Bond](http://scripophily.net/govofpalbear.html)

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://coins.delcampe.com/page/item/id,167366787,var,Palestine-Government-Interest-100-Mils-Bearer-Bond,language,E.html&ei=hrOoUefrN4HkyAGQ5IHQDg&sa=X&oi=unauthorizedredirect&ct=targetlink&ust=1370012302916916&usg=AFQjCNF9YNrnsc0JIkaZDUS6kRQAkM4CMA) is an image that looks remarkably like yours. (If there are problems with that link, I may have to correct them later).

Comment: http://coins.delcampe.com/page/item/id,167366787,var,Palestine-Government-Interest-100-Mils-Bearer-Bond,language,E.html works.

Comment: Is this the entire bond or an interest-coupon?  (For some type of bonds, you have a row of such coupons which are clipped off the bond itself and exchanged for an interest-payment on specified dates.)

Comment: I'm less certain of this, but based on [this](http://www.wcfia.harvard.edu/misc/publications/centerpiece/fall10_vol25_no1/pics/smitter_bondcertificate.jpg), I suspect that what you have is an interest coupon.